# Approximate Hamiltonian in variational method (Example of Helium atom)

Tags: quantum-chemistry

As one know, the exact Helium Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
        \hat H = 
        \left( -\frac{\hbar}{2m_e}\Delta_1 - \frac{Ze^2}{r_1} \right)
        + 
        \left( -\frac{\hbar}{2m_e}\Delta_2 - \frac{Ze^2}{r_2} \right) +
        \frac{e^2}{r_{12}}
    \end{equation}

Now, we can use variational method for determining approximate value of energy of ground state with $\Phi = \frac{\zeta^3}{\pi}e^{-\zeta(r_1 + r_2)}$ as
\begin{equation}
        E_{0_{\min}} = -\zeta_{\min}^2 = -\left(Z - 5/16\right)^2 = -\left(Z - \sigma\right)^2.
    \end{equation}
Can we say that we actually found the Hamiltonian for a given function $\Phi(r_1,r_2;\zeta_{\min})$ in form
\begin{equation}
        \hat H_0 = 
        \left( -\frac{\hbar}{2m_e}\Delta_1 - \frac{(Z-\sigma)e^2}{r_1} \right)
        + 
        \left( -\frac{\hbar}{2m_e}\Delta_2 - \frac{(Z-\sigma)e^2}{r_2} \right)
    \end{equation}
? I.e. is the such $\Phi(r_1,r_2;\zeta_{\min})$ eigenfunction of $\hat{H}_0$?